# Evaluate a bean expression with Spring EL with application context beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I've been working on this a few days, searching for a solution but I'm stuck.

It's similar to this other answered question:
[Programmatically evaluate a bean expression with Spring Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616316/programmatically-evaluate-a-bean-expression-with-spring-expression-language)

In my java application (command line, not web) I'm using Spring to wire the application classes. In my `applicationContext.xml` I have this

```
<bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="location" value="classpath:config/#{systemProperties['ENV']?:'LOCAL'}.properties"/> 
</bean>
```

This works fine.
Inside my app I want to evaluate  similar strings, and I've developed this method

```
@Component("myAppAware ") 
public class MyAppAware implements BeanFactoryAware { 

@Autowired 
private ApplicationContext applicationContext; 


private BeanFactory beanFactory; 

@Override 
public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException { this.beanFactory = beanFactory; } 

public String process(){ 
    String toParse = "classpath:config/#{systemProperties['ENV']?:'LOCAL'}.properties"; 
    BeanFactoryResolver beanFactoryResolver = new BeanFactoryResolver(beanFactory); 
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(); 
    context.setBeanResolver(beanFactoryResolver); 
    SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(); 
    TemplateParserContext templateContext = new TemplateParserContext(); 
    Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(toParse,templateContext); 
    Object ovalue = expression.getValue(context); // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE !!! 
    String value = ovalue.toString(); 
    return value; 
}
```

But when I run this code, a error is thrown

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Field or property 'systemProperties' cannot be found on null 
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:243) 
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:112) 
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:107)
```

I think I'm near my objective, but I do not know how to get application context beans into he parser, or how to get it working
anyone could help ?

Comment: Which Spring version are you using? Also, could you try without the `TemplateParserContext`, like `new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(toParse).getValue()`?

Comment: Try to construct objectives when parsing EL expressions.

Comment: Without the  `TemplateParserContext`, the `#{ }` does not work.

Comment: My Spring version is 3.2.4, thanks

Comment: How do I construct objectives when parsing EL expressions ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
String toParse = "classpath:config/#{@systemProperties['ENV']?:'LOCAL'}.properties";
```

If you really have `systemProperties` bean there...

With an XML definition it works a bit different because it is based on the `StandardBeanExpressionResolver`. But is a bit complex to use from the target application.

**UPDATE**

```
this.expressionContext = (beanFactory != null ? new BeanExpressionContext(beanFactory, null) : null);
 ...............
private Object resolveDefaultValue(String defaultValue) {
    if (this.configurableBeanFactory == null) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    String placeholdersResolved = this.configurableBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(defaultValue);
    BeanExpressionResolver exprResolver = this.configurableBeanFactory.getBeanExpressionResolver();
    if (exprResolver == null) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return exprResolver.evaluate(placeholdersResolved, this.expressionContext);
}
```

See `AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver` source code.

Comment: The @ syntax works, however I would like to use the `#{systemProperties['ENV']}`like in the applicationContext,xml. do you know how to make the  `StandartBeanExpressionResolver´to work ? I've been searching but nothing clear found.