# How to customize the programmatically evaluation of a bean expression with Spring Expression Language

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am trying to evaluate a expression using SpEL programatically.
I could evaluate the below expression.
`@expressionUtil.substractDates(#fromDate,#toDate)`

Is it possible to remove the symbols `@` and `#` ?

So the new expression will be like `expressionUtil.substractDates(fromDate,toDate)`..

Comment: Don't you think that if that was possible, there would be no `@` and `#` in spring spel?

Comment: Check the edit of this answer.. There are possibilities to remove @ I am planning to avoid both @ and # . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616316/programmatically-evaluate-a-bean-expression-with-spring-expression-language/11616942?noredirect=1#comment74193865_11616942

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what your motivation is; `fromDate` and `toDate` are variables, indicated by `#`, the `@` signals that the bean resolver needs to be consulted.

It's all about the root object of the evaluation. You can do what you want with a simple javabean as a wrapper...

```
final ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("expressionUtil.subtractDates(fromDate, toDate)");
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
wrapper.setFromDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
wrapper.setToDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
Long value = expression.getValue(wrapper, Long.class);
System.out.println(value);

...

public static class Wrapper {

    private final ExpressionUtil expressionUtil = new ExpressionUtil();

    private Date fromDate;

    private Date toDate;

    public Date getFromDate() {
        return this.fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    public Date getToDate() {
        return this.toDate;
    }

    public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }

    public ExpressionUtil getExpressionUtil() {
        return this.expressionUtil;
    }

}

public static class ExpressionUtil {

    public long subtractDates(Date from, Date to) {
        return to.getTime() - from.getTime();
    }

}
```

Or you can even do it with a `Map`, but in that case, you have to add a `MapAccessor` to the evaluation context, because it doesn't have one by default...

```
final ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.addPropertyAccessor(new MapAccessor());
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("expressionUtil.subtractDates(fromDate, toDate)");
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("expressionUtil", new ExpressionUtil());
map.put("fromDate", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
map.put("toDate", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
Long value = expression.getValue(context, map, Long.class);
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: MapAccessor will be the best option for me, Variables are dynamic in each evaluation.